# C# loading listView subItems from file using StreamReader

Tags: c#, listview, streamreader

I need some help with loading text file into a listView. Text file looks like this:

1,6 sec,5 sec,1 sec,17,
2,6 sec,4 sec,2 sec,33,
3,7 sec,5 sec,3 sec,44,

I have to load this into a listView control and every subitem should be separated by comma (or any other character). I tried something like this:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
   string fileLine = sr.ReadLine();
   foreach (string piece in fileLine.Split(',')) 
   {     
      listView1.Items.Add(piece); 
   } 
   sr.Close(); 
}
```

it would work just fine apart from only first line is loaded to the first column in listview. I cannot figure it out.

Thanks for your time!
KR!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to advance to the next line, you can use a `while`-loop:

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
    string fileLine;
    while ((fileLine = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        foreach (string piece in fileLine.Split(','))
        {
            listView1.Items.Add(piece);
        }
    }
}
```

Note that you don't need to close the stream manually, that is done by the using-statement.

Another way is using `File.ReadLines` or `File.ReadAllLines` which can help to simplify your code:

```
var allPieces = File.ReadLines(file).SelectMany(line => line.Split(','));
foreach(string piece in allPieces)
    listView1.Items.Add(piece);
```

Comment: Thanks! That was helpful, however I need to write under.net 3.5 due to client system limitations. Unfortunately File.ReadLines is not supported there. Any ideas why listView is loosing formating after loading content to it?

Comment: @Luka: then you just have to use `File.ReadAllLines` instead (or the `StreamReader`). The only difference is that it reads all lines into memory.

Answer (score 0):

Ι guess you just have to add:

```
while (!sr.EndOfStream)
{
                string fileLine = sr.ReadLine();
                foreach (string piece in fileLine.Split(',')) 
                {     
                        listView1.Items.Add(piece); 
                } 
}
```

sr.Close();// close put the end of while scope beacause you have a multiline text this code can't be read second line, and throw exceptions this code.

Answer (score 0):

```
using (var sr = new StreamReader(file))
{
     while(!sr.EndOfStream)
     {
          string fileLine = sr.ReadLine();
          foreach (string piece in fileLine.Split(',')) 
          {     
              listView1.Items.Add(piece); 
          } 
          sr.Close(); 
     }
}
```